# Why does not ContourPlot consider the condition given in RegionFunction in the given code?

Tags: plotting, regions, assumptions, conditional

I have two functions $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$. I am using  `RegionFunction` in  `ContourPlot` to see those values of $(x,y)$ for which $f=g$ assuming $-1<g<1$. I use this code

```
f := Cos[x y] + (2 Sin[x y])/x + (-(1/2) + Cos[6 x]) Csc[6 x] Sin[x y];
g := Cos[x y] + Sin[x y]/( 2 x) + (-(1/2) + Cos[6 x]) Csc[6 x] Sin[x y] +  Sqrt[-1 + (Cos[x y] + ((1 + 2 x Cot[6 x] - x Csc[6 x]) Sin[x y])/( 2 x))^2];

p1 = ContourPlot[ f == g , {y, 0, 2}, {x, 0, 3},  ContourStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.006]], PlotPoints -> 50, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y},  -1 < g < 1   ]];
```

Then, I check to see if the result of the given plot is correct (i.e. they satisfy the condition $-1<g<1$)

```
p2 = RegionPlot[  -1 < g < 1  , {y, 0, 2}, {x, 0, 3}, PlotStyle -> Green, BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0]],   PlotPoints -> 80, FrameLabel -> {"y", "x"}];

Show[{p2, p1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

and I get this

[image]

which shows that  `ContourPlot` does not consider the condition in  `RegionFunction` exactly (for some parts). How can I solve this issue? I mean how can I modify the given code to get only those lines which are located in the green area of the given plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reasonable results can be obtained with a few changes to code.  First, we can define $f$ and $g$ like this

```
ClearAll[f, g]
f[x_, y_] := 
 Cos[x y] + (2 Sin[x y])/x + (-(1/2) + Cos[6 x]) Csc[6 x] Sin[x y]
g[x_, y_] := 
 Cos[x y] + Sin[x y]/(2 x) + (-(1/2) + Cos[6 x]) Csc[6 x] Sin[x y] + 
  Sqrt[-1 + (Cos[
        x y] + ((1 + 2 x Cot[6 x] - x Csc[6 x]) Sin[x y])/(2 x))^2]
```

We notice the $\csc(6x)$ will produce singularities at $x=n\pi/6$, so we want to look at the region $0<x<\pi/6$ first.  Later we will expand this region.  Let's start with $n=1$, a parameter that is only used in the plot limits.

For the plots we will make $x$ horizontal and $y$ vertical to avoid confusion.  We can change them *after* we get reasonable results.  We must also change the `RegionFunction` a little. It takes 3 parameters, and they must be in the correct order. The original region function produced a few error messages, but this version seems to be message-free.

```
n = 1; ymax=6;

p1 = ContourPlot[f[x, y] == g[x, y], {x, 0, n*\[Pi]/6}, {y, 0, ymax},
   ContourStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.006]], 
   PlotPoints -> 50, 
   RegionFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y, z}, 
     x != 0 && Im[g[x, y]] == 0 && -1 < g[x, y] < 1]];

p2 = RegionPlot[
   Im[g[x, y]] == 0 && -1 < g[x, y] < 1, {x, 0, n*\[Pi]/6}, {y, 0, ymax},
    PlotStyle -> Green, BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0]], 
   PlotPoints -> 80, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}];

Show[{p2, p1}, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Small]
```

[image]

Now the value of $n$ can be increased and other adjustments can be made.

Comment: Thanks. What is the role of the $z$ variable in your code? @LouisB

Comment: @math2021 `ContourPlot` passes three values to the `RegionFunction`, so I put in 3 variable names as arguments.  It's an old habit I picked up to check the docs and see what the arguments are.  Maybe it's not required, but I would still put it in, if only remind myself that it is available., even if it is not actually used, as in this case.  I believe it would have the (Boolean) value of `f[x,y] == g[x,y]`.